# Assigning uploaded files from google form in appropriate google drive folder

Tags: javascript

I need help get my script to work on a form.

I was able to create script that allows me to create subfolders(Countries) but I am struggling with being able to assign uploaded documents from a google Form in the appropriate subfolder (per country).

```
function start(){

  var ClusterID

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var names = ss.getSheetByName("APC");

  var form = FormApp.openByUrl(names.getFormUrl());
  var length = form.getResponses().length;
  var name = form.getResponses()[length-1].getItemResponses()[0].getResponse();
  var uploadedFileId=form.getResponses()[length-1].getItemResponses()[1].getResponse();

  var SupplierName = names.getRange(names.getLastRow(),7).getValue();
  var Cluster = names.getRange(names.getLastRow(),3).getValue();

  if (Cluster == 'US') {
  ClusterID = DriveApp.getFolderById("ID here");
    var files = DriveApp.getFiles();
    while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
  var newFolderID = ClusterID.createFolder(SupplierName).addFile(file);
  return newFolderID.getId();  
  }}
```

Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong. I made it work the once but something happened that it doesn't work anymore.